# Binding a combobox selectedvalue in Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox as a column in a gridview and it is bound to a local property like so:

```
<ComboBox Name="cboMetaDataTypes" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=MetaDataTypes}" 
DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key"/>
```

The Source MetaDataTypes is a List of KeyValuePairs where the Value property is displayed as you can see.

Now I am stuck. I want to bind the selected value to the Key that matches the Key of the Column. And I want the selected value to be bound to a local property. I tried a lot but I cannot make it happen. 
Can anyone give me directions?

Thank You.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I want the selected value to be bound to a local property."?  Do you mean a property of your window's class?

Comment: The problem is the dataTable bound to the grid has an ID for a "MetaDataType". Now i have a Combobox with the names of the MetaDataTypes. I want the correct MetaDataType selected in the Combobox, where the ID matches the Key of the Comboboxes itemsSource. Then i want the selected value of the combobox to be bound to a property in my code-behind. I hope i made myself somewhat clearer. Sorry. No native english-speaker here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you want, you want to bind the `SelectedValue` property to a property in your Window's class (as defined in the MyWindow.xaml.cs file).  The best way to do that, in my experience, is to assign your window class a Name like this:

```
<Window x:Name="myWindow" ... >
```

And then you can do the following with your ComboBox

```
<ComboBox Name="cboMetaDataTypes" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
          FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=MetaDataTypes}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key"
          SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=myProperty }" />
```

You may need to define your `myProperty` as a dependency property to get two way data-binding  to work properly.

Comment: i want the selected value to be bound to my dataRow. The ItemsSource of my Combobox is a List of KeyValuePairs. And the Key should match an ID in my Row. I thought it would work with SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MetaDataTypeID}" but it wont...

Comment: My god. Yes this definitely the way to do it. I messed something else up. Sorry for the late accept. Also for more info on dependency properties see here http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html